# Flash AS3: Spontaneous 5001 error, relating to letter-case of folder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, uppercase, lowercase

After updating some sound files in the .fla library, I started getting 5001 (name of package does not reflect location) errors for every file in an unrelated folder.
I understand the 5001 error, had it many times during development, but it was usually a case of a package typo, or a file in the wrong folder.  Here, however, it seems to be some sort of letter case issue.

In the "Location" section of the "Compiler Errors" output, it lists the locations of every error (ie, every class in the /options/ folder) as "C:\Users...\powerups\Options\ClassName.as", note the upper-case \Options.

However, when I look at the (Windows) properties of any files in the /options/ folder, it confirms that the folder is lower-case, listing its location as "C:\Users...\powerups\options".
When I let Flash auto-suggest the package path it just suggests what it already was.

I fixed it on one occasion without changing anything by closing Flash and reopening, but then it starting occurring again after a few successful compiles.  Have not had any luck since - tried recreating a fresh folder, letting Flash recreate the project files, and restarting.

I'm fairly certain I haven't changed any relevant code - the only thing I've been doing is adding some sound clips to the library and updating old ones.

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure that you have correct settings in the tab "Advanced ActionScript 3.0 Settings" of the Flash IDE?
Maybe [this link](http://ayumiloveflash.wordpress.com/2010/09/14/actionscript-error-5001-the-name-of-package-does-not-reflect-the-location-of-this-file/) will be usefull for you.

Comment: Pretty sure those settings are correct - haven't changed them in a long time and it's been working fine.  Document Class is called "DocumentClass" and is in same directory as the .fla.  Source path is simply ".".  Classes are in com._____._____ directories and packaged and imported accordingly.
Link didn't shed any light, but thanks anyway.